# Besides the writings of John, what is the biblical evidence Jesus Christ is the Only-begotten Son of God?

Tags: biblical-basis, nature-of-god, christology

Apart from John's writings, what is the Biblical evidence that Jesus Christ is the **only-begotten son of God**?

John makes it clear (such as in John 1:18, 3:18), but other parts of the Bible refer to many "sons of God", in both the Old Testament and the New.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Why would you want proof besides John 1:18 and John 3:18? I am trying to understand the reasoning behind this.

Comment: @LoveTheFaith - because Jehovah's witnesses translate those words as "the only begotten god" and like it or not but that way of translation of that word is also possible.

Comment: I see. Perhaps it will help if you ask them what it means to be a son, as I have done in my post! :)

Comment: What's the purpose of your comment about "blood transfusion and coffee drinking"?  I don't understand how those are at all related to the nature of Jesus.

Comment: @Joe - because Jehovah's witnesses and Mormons do consider Jesus to be a god, but they don't believe that He is the God, so their understanding of the nature of Jesus is quite different from the main-stream Christianity understanding. Since on this site we are supposed to consider them Christians, but to me it would be impossible - I wouldn't be able to say "all Christians except for Jehovah's witnesses and Mormons", I decided to take them out of my audience in the way of using other points of their teaching that they insist on (blood transfusion - JW, coffee consumption - Mormons)

Comment: @Brilliant Peter confessed, "You are the Christ, the Son of the living God" (Matt 16:16; cf. Mark 8:29; John 11:27). John described the purpose of his gospel as that “these have been written so that you may believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that believing you may have life in His name” (John 20:31). Jesus prayed, “This is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent_” (John 17:3). What is the Biblical basis for you claim that, to be saved, one has to believe that Jesus is God?

Comment: @Andries: 1st Cor. 1:2 + 1st Cor 8:5,6 + Act 9:14,21 + Mrk 12:29 + John 14:9. It is very clear from the NT that the early Christians were worshipping Jesus in their prayers. It is also clear that they all followed the first commandment, that is, they believed that there was only One God and that they were supposed to worship only that One God. This, however, didn’t stop them from worshipping Christ. Praying to Jesus didn’t strike them as contradictory to their faith, which was only possible in case they believed that by praying to Jesus they were praying to God Himself.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The term "only begotten" is a translation of the Greek word "monogenes".  "Mono" indicates one and "genes" indicates kind.  So, the very word itself indicates a meaning of "one of a kind".

In the Septuagint (the Greek translation of the Old Testament), the word was actually used of Isaac.  It should be noted that Isaac was not, in fact, the only son of Abraham.  He was neither the first nor the last, as Ishmael preceded him and the sons of Keturah came from Abraham's second marriage that followed the death of Sarah.  (Abraham did, indeed, "have many sons".)

Still, Isaac's "sonship" was wholly unlike all the others ("one of a kind") in that he was the son of the promise and came from a miraculous birth from a woman who was well past the age of childbearing.

As @Mike noted, followers of Jesus are called "sons and daughters of God".  However, this is quite different from the "sonship" of Jesus.  His "sonship" is wholly unlike any other, in that it is eternal.  Indeed, His birth into this world was miraculous as well.

So, Jesus is not the only "son" of God, but His "sonship" is unique, one-of-a-kind, and distinct from all others who are called sons and daughters of God.  He is literally the Monogenes--the One-of-a Kind--eternal Son of God.

Comment: Your whole answer seems to be based on the translation of the word "only-begotten", and the only book in the Bible that uses that word directly in reference to Jesus is the Gospel of John. Therefore, your whole answer given here is only valid when you consider the Gospel of John. My question, however, is requesting the proof from outside of the Gospel of John.

Comment: @brilliant The rest of the Bible confirms the distinct nature of Jesus and thereby implicitly confirms this teaching.  Nowhere else in Scripture is anyone given anything close to equality with Jesus.

Comment: Well, I agree with that. Mormons also agree with that, however, it doesn't stop them from claiming that Lucifer is yet another Son of God.

Comment: @brilliant Yes, but that claim can not be soundly demonstrated from anything in the Bible.  The Bible affirms what is true.  It does not identify every untruth that anyone could ever come up with and say that it is wrong.

Comment: That's why I tried to look for a proof from the Bible, but outside of John's writings.

Answer (score 12):

### Begotten = Same Nature

Think of what it means to be a begotten son. A begotten son of a human, is human by nature. A begotten son of God therefore, is God by nature. This is the key.

### Nature of God

What is the nature of God? Let's take just one quality of God - **eternity**. God, by definition, is eternal by nature. He is timeless. He wasn't created, but he himself is the beginning and the end, if we can use those terms for him. A begotten son of God therefore should also be eternal. Indeed **Jesus Christ is eternal** (John 1:1, Revelation 22:13). And he is a son of God (Matthew 16:16-17), and "bears the very stamp of God's nature" (Hebrews 1:3). Jesus is therefore **a** begotten son of God.

*So far, we have proved that Jesus is **a** begotten son of God. Now, we have to prove that he is the **only** begotten son of God.*

### Nature of angels and humans

Who else are the candidates? Angels and humans. The Bible also calls angels (Job 1:6) and humans (Gal 3:26) "sons of God". But are they "sons of God" by nature? No. Angels were created (Psalm 148:5) and humans were created too (Genesis 1). Therefore, **they are not eternal by nature** and therefore, they cannot be begotten sons of God. They have to be **adopted** sons of God (Romans 8:14-15, Galatians 4:5). Through their adoption, they **participate** in God's own divine **nature** (2 Peter 1:4) and are therefore sons of God (1 John 3:1). Although the Bible doesn't mention how exactly angels are sons of God, since we know they are created beings, we have to conclude that they are not begotten sons of God but should be adopted sons of God.

### Conclusion

Besides, the Bible also says that Jesus is the **only** son of God in 1 John 4:9 and also in the verses that you mentioned (John 1:18, John 3:18).

What can we conclude from this? The conclusion is that Jesus is the **only begotten** son of God.

Comment: Nice answer!  This was a very interesting read.  Also, thanks for taking the time to include so many references.

Comment: Wow! Really nice answer. Can I upvote it twice? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The Greek word translated "only begotten" (*monogenes*) is a compound word of *monos* (one/only) and *genos* (offspring/kind) and means "only offspring" in every occurrence in the New Testament, and does not prove Christ's begottenness but only his being "the sole offspring" of the Father.

The Word is the "only offspring" of the Father (John 1:14) but all humans collectively are also "offspring" of the Father (Acts 17:28), so is this a contradiction? No. John explains why. It is because the Word is "the only offspring who is God as to his nature" (John 1:18).

In Romans 1:4 Paul wrote that Christ was declared or *made known* to the world as God's Son with power **at his resurrection** according to his spirit of holiness, i.e. divine nature (not the third person of the Trinity). Paul is very explicit here; Jesus is "God's Son" according to his divine nature.

In coherence with Romans 1:4, Paul elucidates in Acts 13:33, Hebrews 1:5 and Hebrews 5:5 that Christ was declared, *not made*, to be "God's begotten" Son **at his resurrection.**

And Paul adds more; he said that the Son is the "first-begotten" of the Father (Col. 1:15) which is in apposition to the clause which precedes it, meaning, the Son is the **uncreated** "Image of the Father" (*homoousios*) as opposed to us humans who were **created** in the "Image of the Trinity" per Genesis 1:26-27 and hence, *heteroousios* (of a different substance).

The Divine Wisdom in the LXX Proverbs 8:25 is said to be born by God (Greek *genna*) before creation.
The Messiah in the LXX Psalm 110:3 is said to be born by God from his womb before creation.

In conclusion, the Apostle Paul explains the Sonship of the Word by his "birth" and John elucidates it by his being the "only offspring" of the Father. Both metaphors prove that the Word is consubstantial with the Father. The Word is the only offspring of the Father, birthed by him and hence, equal to him in nature, or as the Nicene Creed puts it "only begotten, born not made, of one nature with the Father."

Answer (score 1):

All Christians are 'sons of God', but only Jesus was born of a Virgin by the Holy Spirit. That is what the Bible means 'only son'.

> The virgin will be with child and will give birth to a son, and they will call him Immanuel” which means, “God with us.” (Mathew 1:23)

The idea of 'son of God' simply means those who bear his image. Adam and Eve were by nature the 'sons of God'. They stood in relation of 'sons' to God by the communication of his image and likeness. On the same account the angels are frequently called the 'sons of God'. God in His divine wisdom also recovered sinners and re-created his image in them as 'sons' by adoption. This adoption was through Christ, who was Himself the essential and eternal Son of God.

So the proof that Jesus was the 'Only' son of God refers to God joining Himself with humanity by the Virgin birth.  So your question is actually is there any proof that only Jesus was born of a virgin by the Holy Spirit.  The answer seems clear if we read the gospel accounts, there is no other Son.

I do not recall anyone else claiming to have been born from a virgin and believed to be the Messiah. If there was such a person, I am sure we would find they did not fulfill the scores of other Old Testament prophecies concerning Christ.

Comment: Do you mean to say that He was not the Son of God before His incarnation?

Comment: @brilliant It sounds like Mike is saying that Jesus was always (eternally) the Son of God, but is referred to as "only begotten" because of the virgin birth.

Comment: Jas3.1 is stating the facts. The pre-existant eternal Son of God was claimed by the Father to be his 'Son' in john's babptism. Then later the Jews wanted to stone him for saying before Abraham was 'I am'. Jeus was either very God of God or a blasphemer to be stoned under the law of moses.

Comment: @Mike - I see. Thank you. I think it opens another big question. I asked it here: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8025/is-there-any-proof-from-the-bible-that-the-second-person-of-the-trinity-was-the

Answer (score 1):

The word "son" has a variety of meanings depending upon the context. For example, Paul calls Timothy his son (1 Timothy 1:2, 18) and yet Timothy was not his offspring. In the Bible, Israel is called God's son (Exodus 4:22), angels are called sons of God (Job 1:6; 2:1; 38:7), and Christians are called sons of God (Romans 8:14,19; Gal 3:26). In each of these cases, the word "son" means something different.

In some cases, father/son refers to the loving and close relationship that exists between two people. In others, it refers to the authorial relationship where the father rules over the son. In other cases, it deals with the similarity of traits, characteristics, or behaviors. A child will often be "like" the parent. At other times, it refers to the relationship of property or rights. A son will inherit the father's position and property. In other cases, it is talking about the source or origin of one thing to another. So, for example, Jesus calls the Devil the father of lies (John 8:44) since he is the source of the first lie. Lastly, father/son refers to offspring in the sense of giving "birth".

So, when the Bible says that Jesus is the "only Son of God", what does it mean?

It is helpful to understand that the phrase "Son of God" when applied to Jesus is not just a description, it is also a title. For example, while there a many different presidents in the United States, there is only one President of the United States. When I talk about the President, you know who I am talking about because that is his title.

So, why does Jesus have that title? What makes him the "Son of God" and the only one? Well, to answer that question, we need to ask, "How did the people of Jesus' day understand it?"

When Jesus used this title to describe Himself, it made some people angry. In fact, they sought to kill him. They accused Him of blasphemy, a most horrendous sin, in which a person curses God. In John 5:18, the reasons behind this are explained more clearly. It says, "the Jews were seeking all the more to kill Him, because He not only was breaking the Sabbath, but also was calling God His own Father, making Himself equal with God." (NAS) By claiming to be the "Son of God", Jesus was claiming to be equal with God. That is how they Jewish people understood the title of "Son of God". This is very different than how we use the phrase in our modern day. The word "son" in English is never used in this way which is why people don't understand what the title "Son of God" actually means. It means that Jesus is God.

That is why the Jews accused Jesus of blasphemy because they did not believe He was in fact God. They were accusing Jesus of lying. At his trial, the high priest questioned Jesus saying, "Are You the Christ, the Son of the Blessed One?" Jesus responded by saying "I am ; and you shall see THE SON OF MAN SITTING AT THE RIGHT HAND OF POWER, and COMING WITH THE CLOUDS OF HEAVEN." (Mark 14:62-63) They then accused Him of blasphemy which according to Jewish law is punishable by death (see Leviticus 24:16).

As for your question as to whether any other parts of the Bible show that Jesus is the only Son of God, the answer is "yes". Everywhere it talks about Jesus' divinity, every time it calls Jesus "Lord", and every place it calls Jesus "Christ" are all references to Him being the "Son of God". Those three titles, "Lord", "Christ", and "Son of God" are all talking about Jesus position and relationship over and to humanity.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It does prove that Jesus is the Son of God, and that by being so He is God. However, it does little proving that Jesus is THE ONLY BEGOTTEN Son of God. For example, your last paragraph starts: "As for your question as to whether any other parts of the Bible show that Jesus is the only Son of God, the answer is "yes"", however, later this paragraph only proves again that Jesus is the Son of God, but not THE ONLY BEGOTTEN Son of God. But THE ONLY BEGOTTEN is, in fact, the main point of my question.

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This next has nothing to do with the quality of your answer, it's just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: @brilliant - The divinity of Christ proves He is the "only begotten" son of God on the basis that there is only one God. I am sorry I didn't make that clear as I thought this was understood.

Comment: @Blake - "The divinity of Christ proves He is the "only begotten" son of God on the basis that there is only one God" - I think you are getting here at some valid point, but I am a bit slow to put two and two together. How does the divinity of Christ prove that He is the only begotten Son? And how does the fact that there is only One God rule out the possibility that God may have, say, two or three Sons?

Comment: @brilliant - Since there is only one God, and the Son of God is divine there can only be one Son of God. A king might have many sons, but only one may take the throne. Additionally, in the first chapter of John, Jesus is referred to as the Word who reveals God and makes Him known. In order for the Word to accurately communicate who God is, since there is one God there will only be one Son.

Comment: @Blake: "Since there is only one God, and the Son of God is divine there can only be one Son of God" - Why? Why One God cannot have two divine Sons?

Comment: @brilliant - If there are two sons, which one is supreme? Which one is God (thus, divine)?

Comment: @Blake: "If there are two sons, which one is supreme? Which one is God (thus, divine)?" - Why only One of the Two Sons should necessarily be supreme and the other One not? And why only One of the two Sons should be divine and the other One not? Why can't both Sons be divine? And why can't both Sons be One and the same God (just like the Father and His Son Jesus Christ are One and the same God)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Apart from John's reference to " Only-begotten" ( John 1:14,18, 3:16,18, 1 Jn 4:9) ,there is a Biblical evidence that Jesus Christ is the only-begotten son of God.

The following are the exegesis of the church fathers concerning the begetting of Christ Jesus, God's Only-Begotten Son:

In 1 John 5:18, Christ is said to be "begotten" from God and in 1 Corinthians 1:24 it is explicitly said that He is God's Wisdom.

> We know that whosoever is born of God sinneth not; but **he that is
>   begotten of God keepeth himself**, and that wicked one toucheth him
>   not. -1 John 5:18 ( KJV)
>
> But unto them which are called, both Jews and Greeks, **Christ** the
>   power of God, and the **wisdom of God**.- 1 Corinthians 1:24 ( KJV)

This idea is found in the Old Testament Scriptures:

In Psalm 110:3 ( LXX)Christ is clearly said to be "begotten" from God.  This proves that Christ is begotten from God and Proverbs 8:25 (LXX) speaks of Wisdom as "begotten" from God.

> " I have begotten you from my womb before the Morning-Star." - Psalm
>   110:3 Septuagint
>
> "Before the hills, He begets me." -Proverbs 8:25 Septuagint

When we examine the entire Old Testament Scriptures, we will find out that God begot no one except Christ and Wisdom which are in fact one and the same as revealed in the New Testament. This shows that in the Old Testament, God has his "only-begotten" Son, namely, Christ himself, God's Wisdom."

Psalm 2:7 (LXX) is quoted in Hebrews 1:5,5:5 and Acts 13:33 which reveals that Christ is God's "begotten" Son through his resurrection based on Romans 1:4, " declared ( not made)to be God's Son with power according to his spirit of holiness (i.e his godhood)." This proves that Christ is God's only begotten Son before creation because the angels weren't begotten but "made" (Heb. 1:7).

In Colossians 1:15, Christ is said to be "First-born/begotten of all creature"  which alludes Proverbs 8:22( LXX) wherein Wisdom said "The Lord created me as the first of his work( activity) , before his works( activities) of old."

It should be noted that there's a big difference between creation ad intra (e.g.begetting) and creation ad extra(e.g.  creation ex nihilo). The former is concerned about "begetting" while the latter is about " making."

According to context ( v. 25), Wisdom is said to be "begotten" and hence, it is talking about creation ad intra.On the otherhand, the context of Colossians 1:15 shows that the Son is of same nature with the Father because of his begetting for he is the "image of the invisible God." God's true image is surely invisible, that is,it's distinct yet same like him.

This is the reason why the early church fathers can use the Greek Version of Proverbs 8:22 for proof that Christ is truly God.He is true God because he is God's own true Son, begotten from him not made out of nothing.It proves that he alone is God's only begotten Son because as already said earlier, Wisdom is Christ himself and only him is said to be begotten from God before creation.

In John 1:1, God only has one Word for he only have one mind and in Psalm 45:1(LXX), this Word of him he emitted, produced, begot. It does not mean that God did literally it but rather, it only means metaphorically that he has a specific relationship with his Word as Father to an Only-begotten Son.It's the reason why the word "Only-begotten"[Greek:monogenes] co-existed with the phrase "the Word" [ Greek: ho logos] in the Prologue of John.

Christians are all "born of God" ( John 1:12-13) and hence, they have "divine nature" ( 2 Peter 1:4) but they only have it by "share"(ibid.) unlike Jesus who has it "fully" ( Colossians 2:9).Why is this so? It is because Christians were born of God metaphorically by means of faith (Gal. 3:26)while Jesus' birth from God metaphorically shows equality of nature ( John 5:18, Philippians 2:6).See how harmonious it is that Christ is born of God that's why he has God's very nature and the same thing is true for Christians albeit in reference to salvation in which they are *being conformed in the image of the Son* (Romans 8:29).Also, because of this truth, it is shown that other sons are "born of God" too and hence, it seems that Christ is not God's "only" begotten Son but do not worry because the Bible itself explains Christ's unique begetting from the Father.John 1:18 says that the One who is in the Father's bosom is the "Only-begotten who is God as to his very nature." [anarthrous *monogenes theos*= P66, Aleph, B,C - substantival in function].What this means is that although God has other birthed sons, he nevertheless has one only-born Son who equally shares in his nature and that's none other than Christ.

And now, last but not least, John 8:42 offers a very compelling proof for Christ's begetting from the Father:

Here's the context of John 8:42:

> 38 I speak that which I have seen with **my Father**: and ye do that which
>   ye have seen with **your father.**
>
> 39 They answered and said unto him, Abraham is our father. Jesus saith
>   unto them, If ye were Abraham's children, ye would do the works of
>   Abraham.
>
> 40 But now ye seek to kill me, a man that hath told you the truth,
>   which I have heard of God: this did not Abraham.
>
> 41 Ye do the deeds of **your father**. Then said they to him, **We be not
>   born of fornication**; **we have one Father, even God**.
>
> 42 Jesus said unto them, If God were your Father, ye would love me:
>   for **I proceeded forth and came from God**; neither came I of myself, but
>   he sent me.
>
> 43 Why do ye not understand my speech? even because ye cannot hear my
>   word.
>
> 44 **Ye are of your father the devil**, and the lusts of your father ye
>   will do. He was a murderer from the beginning, and abode not in the
>   truth, because there is no truth in him. When he speaketh a lie, he
>   speaketh of his own: for he is a liar, and the father of it.

The whole subject matter revolves around son-ship and fatherhood which involves the idea of begetting/born. The Jews said that they weren't illegitimate children, that their Father is God but Jesus refuted their claim, that their father is the Devil because they do not believe his word that he is God's very own Son.In verse 42, Jesus said that He proceeded and came from ( Greek: ἐξῆλθον) God as a begotten/born child from a parent. In Genesis 15:4, the Greek word ἐξῆλθον occurs in the context of a real birth in a child to parent relationship. This word always carry the meaning of a real birth in a child to parent context.This begetting is not from Mary but from God himself and verse 58 further supports this when in it Jesus said that "before Abraham became alive, I am already alive."

Notice that Jesus said that he came from God AND was sent from God.The former is about his begetting from the Father before all ages while the latter is about his mission in the economy of salvation.

*Conclusion:*

These are the Bible verses used in proving that Jesus alone is God's begotten Son:

1 Corinthians 1:24 --> Proverbs 8:25 LXX

1 John 5:18 --> Psalm 110:3

Hebrews 1:5,5:5, Acts 13:35 --> Psalm 2:7

Colossians 1:15--> Proverbs 8:22

John 1:1 --> Psalm 45:1

John 8:42 --> Genesis 15:4

All of these Bible verses were used for the Nicene Creed in its affirmation of the Lord Jesus Christ as "Only begotten, begotten before all ages/ begotten not made, of one nature with the Father."

Answer (score 0):

Please read the first chapter of Hebrews (KJV) in Verse 8 God calls His Son God.

> 8 But unto the Son he saith, Thy throne, O God, is for ever and ever: a sceptre of righteousness is the sceptre of thy kingdom.

also there are many references to Jesus being around before the creation.
and My third and last point, When Jesus came to earth, He was about doing His Father's business, and started what is now known as Christianity (To Be Like Christ).
Why is it so hard for people to just believe what the Word of God actually say'?

Answer (score 0):

Only begotten son is in a biological sense. Mary was his mother and God his father.

> No man hath seen God at any time, the only begotten Son, which is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him.
>   **John 1:18**

The created man Adam, was also considered a son of God.

> Which was the son of Enos, which was the son of Seth, which was the son of Adam, which was the son of God.
>   **Luke 3:38**

Son can also mean descendant, as in "sons of Israel", meaning all descendents of Israel.

The elect are also sons (through Christ in rebirth by baptism).

> But as many as received him, to them gave he power to become the sons of God, even to them that believe on his name:
>   **John 1:12**

Answer (score -1):

(Psa 2:7) "The Lord hath said to me: **Thou art my son**, this day have I begotten thee. Ask of me, and I will give thee the Gentiles for thy inheritance, and the utmost parts of the earth for thy possession."

(Psa 8:4)  "For I will behold thy heavens, the works of thy fingers: the moon and the stars which thou hast founded. **What is man that thou art mindful of him? or the son of man that thou visitest him?"**

(Psa 77:2) **I will open my mouth in parables**: I will utter propositions from the beginning.

So Christ also did not glorify himself, that he might be made a high priest: but he that said unto him: **Thou art my Son, this day have I begotten thee.** 
Hebrews 5:5

Who hath ascended up into heaven, and descended? who hath held the wind in his hands? who hath bound up the waters together as in a garment? who hath raised up all the borders of the earth? what is his name, **and what is the name of his son, if thou knowest?**
Prov 30:4

**"Who is a God like to thee**, who takest away iniquity, and passest by the sin of the remnant of thy inheritance? he will send his fury in no more, because he delighteth in mercy. [19] He will turn again, and have mercy on us: he will put away our iniquities: and he will cast all our sins into the bottom of the sea." (Mic 7:18)

AND THOU, BETHLEHEM Ephrata, art a little one among the thousands of Juda: out of thee shall he come forth unto me that is to be the ruler in Israel: **and his going forth is from the beginning, from the days of eternity** (Micah 5:2)

**God will come from the south,** and the holy one from mount Pharan: His glory covered the heavens, and the earth is full of his praise. [4] His brightness shall be as the light; horns are in his hands: There is his strength hid: [5] Death shall go before his face. And the devil shall go forth before his feet. (Hab 3:3)

This is our God, and there shall no other be accounted of in comparison of him. [37] He found out all the way of knowledge, and gave it to Jacob his servant, and to Israel his beloved. [38] **Afterwards he was seen upon earth, and conversed with men.**  (Baruch 3:36)

**In the beginning was the Word,** and the Word was with God, **and the Word was God**. [2] The same was in the beginning with God. [3] All things were made by him: and without him was made nothing that was made. [4] In him was life, and the life was the light of men. [5] And the light shineth in darkness, and the darkness did not comprehend it.

[6] There was a man sent from God, whose name was John. [7] This man came for a witness, to give testimony of the light, **that all men might believe through him**  John 1:1-7

Comment: Rather than purely quoting verses, please explain their relevance to this question. It would also be good if you formatted them as quotes and noted the translation you've used.

Answer (score -5):

Bible mentions "Son of God" by the Tons. It can be taught of as "Chosen person" and should not be taken literally.

In the book of Psalms 2:7 we find

> Jehovah had said onto me (David), thou art my Son; this day have I begotten thee."

Here in this verse we see that God not only called David his "Son", but also had made him his begotten Son.

hence Clearly Jesus is not the only "begotten" son of God.

The Bible says,

> "And Jesus himself began to be about thirty years of age, being (as was supposed) the son of Joseph, which was the son of Heli." (Luke3:23)

The Bible goes on to mention the supposed genealogy of Jesus Christ. At the end of this genealogy the Bible comes to Adam, and it says,

> "Which was the son of Enos, which was the son of Seth, which was the son of Adam, which was the son of God." (Luke 3:38).

So Adam is also the son of God.

Comment: Did you miss the fact that Jesus is referred to in the Bible as the ONLY-begotten Son? It's true that Adam is called a son of God, and the book of Job, for example, speaks of sons of God, as well as that psalm that you are quoting, however, Bible also calls Jesus the Only-begotten Son of God, a title that has not been given in the Bible to Adam or anyone else. So, if you accept the whole Bible, and not just some of its parts, you must acknowledge that the sonship of Jesus is quite different from that of Adam or others. It is in terms of this unique sonship that Jesus is the Only-begotten One.

Comment: In the book of Psalms 2:7 we find

"I will declare the decree: the LORD hath said unto me, Thou art my Son; this day have I ***begotten*** thee." David, in this verse, is saying that God had told him he was the son of God and God has "begotten" him.

Comment: So, how does that change the point I made in my previous comment? No doubt, David said that. However, David didn't say "you have begotten ONLY me". Bible is very precise in this matter. The ONLY-begotten-ness is ascribed in the Bible only to Jesus. Yes, David was used in the Bible as a prototype of Jesus, however, David's sonship is way lower then the sonship of Jesus, which is indicated in such passages as Matthew 22:41-46 and Acts 2: 25-34. Jesus' sonship is quite unique, only He possesses that kind of sonship, hence, in the Bible He is referred to as the only-begotten Son of God.

Comment: The Son in Psalm 2 does not refer to David.  As you can see in verse 12, David exhorts people to "Kiss the Son,
    lest he be angry, and you perish in the way,
    for his wrath is quickly kindled.
Blessed are all who take refuge in him."  David says over and over again that "the Lord is his refuge."  David is not the refuge for anyone.  So, this is quite clearly not referring to David.

Comment: Adam is clearly a special creation of God--quite distinct from how Seth was the son of Adam.  Also, Adam was mortal, while the Bible clearly identifies Jesus as eternal.