# What is the significance of Jesus saying "I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending"?

Tags: exegesis, life-of-jesus, revelation, names-of-god, words-of-jesus

All Scriptures are quoted from the King James translation.

Four times in the Revelation Jesus uses that phrase(they are all in red letters):

> Revelation 1:8  ***I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the ending***, saith the Lord, which is, and which was, and which is to come, the Almighty.
>
> Revelation 1:11  Saying, ***I am Alpha and Omega, the first and the last***: and, What thou seest, write in a book, and send it unto the seven churches which are in Asia; unto Ephesus, and unto Smyrna, and unto Pergamos, and unto Thyatira, and unto Sardis, and unto Philadelphia, and unto Laodicea.
>
> Revelation 21:6  And he said unto me, It is done. ***I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end***. I will give unto him that is athirst of the fountain of the water of life freely.
>
> Revelation 22:13  ***I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end***, the first and the last.

But we know that Jesus was existent at Creation or before since:

> Luke 10:18  And he said unto them, *I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven*.

It appears that Jesus had some other motive for using those particular words, rather than Eternal.

Comment: But Rev. 1:8 is not Jesus speaking. ὁ ὢν καὶ ὁ ἦν καὶ ὁ ἐρχόμενος is a reference to the Father. See Rev. 1:4 and the distinction indicated by the following copula in Rev. 1:5 (where Jesus is then mentioned). Also that statement in Rev. 1:11 (Ἐγώ ἐιμι τὸ Α καὶ τὸ Ω, Ὃ πρῶτος καὶ ὁ ἔσχατος καὶ) is "without attestation" (Meyer) and absent in many manuscripts. Rev. 22:13 is definitely Jesus though. :)

Comment: It shows his eternal nature and thus his divinity - http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8002/does-the-bible-have-any-proof-that-jesus-christ-is-the-only-begotten-son-of-god/8015#8015

Comment: Are you implying that Satan fell from Heaven _before_ Creation?

Comment: @Andrew no I am implying that Satan fell at Creation, my Bible tells me.

Comment: @BYE how could a created being fall “at” creation? Wouldn’t he have had to fall “after” creation.

Comment: @!Andrew The creation of all things material has nothing to do with the creation of Angels which are Spiritual creations. exactly when Angels were created; as far as i know, is not given to us in the Bible. All we are given is that whenever that did happen is that Jesus was there. >Luke 10:18 KJV  And he said unto them, I beheld Satan as lightning fall from heaven. .We are also given:    Cointinued

Comment: Rev 12:7  And there was war in heaven: Michael and his angels fought against the dragon; and the dragon fought and his angels, 
Rev 12:8  And prevailed not; neither was their place found any more in heaven. 
Rev 12:9  And the great dragon was cast out, that old serpent, called the Devil, and Satan, which deceiveth the whole world: he was cast out into the earth, and his angels were cast out with him. If this is addressed anywher else in the Bible I am unaware of it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a powerful assertion of Deity by Jesus.  You are correct that it is, in fact, Jesus Himself who is speaking here and not the Father.  That is made clear in this passage, as Jesus was the One who "*was dead*" and is now "*alive forevermore*".

> 17 When I saw Him, I fell at His feet like a dead man. And He placed His right hand on me, saying, “Do not be afraid; **I am the first and the last**, 18 and **the living One**; and I **was dead, and behold, I am alive forevermore**, and I have the keys of death and of Hades.  Revelation 1:17-18 NASB

Jesus is, indeed, the Alpha and the Omega, the First and the Last, the Beginning and the End, **the Almighty**.

Paul's letter to the Colossians is also simliar:

> He is also head of the body, the church; and **He is the beginning**, the firstborn from the dead, so that He Himself will come to have first place in everything.   Colossians 1:15 NASB

It is noteworthy to reference the passage in Isaiah where God states something very similar:

> “Who has performed and accomplished it, Calling forth the generations from the beginning?
>   ‘I, the Lord, am **the first**, and with **the last**. I am He.’”  Isaiah 41:4 NASB

So, it was God (the LORD) in the Old Testament who claimed to be the First and the Last, and it is Jesus Himself who makes that very same claim in the New Testament.  God alone is the First and the Last, and Jesus claims to be God Almighty in an unmistakable manner.

Answer (score 5):

The Alpha is the first letter of the *Alpha*-bet.  The Omega is the last letter thereof.

Jesus is simply saying, as he is three verses latter - "I am at the beginning, I am at the end."

From a human perspective, the best we can do is understand that Jesus is eternal.  (By the way, John 1:2 is a better support for that.)  For highly concrete original hearers, re-focusing them on the eternal via metaphors they use made the idea sink in.

Answer (score 1):

It is believed that Jesus, even assumed, that Jesus said this, implying he is "[Almighty] God", in turn, "The Father".

However, on the other side of the spectrum, verses **Revelation 1:8, 21:6 and 22:13** identifies not Jesus, but rather, The Father Himself. This is obvious when you check out the references.

**Alpha and omega** are the first and last letters of the Greek alphabet. The respective positions of these letters in the Greek alphabet are used to illustrate that God [*Yahweh or Jehovah in modern English*] alone is the beginning and the end, which brings us to Revelation 21:6. For The Most High is Almighty God, and he will continue to be Almighty God forever and ever. He is the only one who can be noted as from everlasting to everlasting (Psalm 90:2).

The final occurrence we see in Revelation 22:13. It is evident that a number of persons are represented as speaking in this chapter of Revelation, mainly verses 8 and 9, show that the angel spoke to Apostle John. Verse 16 obviously applies to the Lord himself - Jesus, the first part of verse 17 is credited to the spirit and to the bride of the Lamb, and the one speaking in the latter part of verse 20 is manifestly John himself.

The Alpha and the Omega of verses 12-15 properly be identified as the same one who bears the title in the other two occurrences, God our Father. The expression such as Look, I am coming quickly, in verse 12, does not require that these aforementioned verses apply to Jesus, inasmuch as God also speaks of himself as coming” to execute his judgment. This can also be compared with Isaiah 26:21. In Malachi 3:1-6, it speaks of a joint coming for judgment on the part of God our Father and his Messenger of the Covenant..

Now we have Revelation 1:11 from a Textual Citric standpoint. The additional occurrence of this phrase in the King James version of Revelation 1:11 (and or any translation that shares later MSS), the reality is, it does not receive much support from some of the oldest Greek manuscripts copies that we have, including the Alexandrine, Sinaitic, and Codex Ephraemi rescriptus. It is, therefore, omitted in many modern and or revised Bible translations.

A sidenote, Jesus is the first and last of a new creation that is to come whereas the creation of God begins and it connects to God's original purpose, for example, we have the New Covenant.

Answer (score 0):

The common assumption is that Jesus is saying he is the beginning and end, and therefore eternal as the Father.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, the terminology of Alpha/Omega or Aleph/Tav (as it was in Hebrew), Beginning/End, First/Last indicate entirety. That is He is the entirety of things, the all-encompassing God of everything. That claim is supported by verses like Col 1:15ff, 2:9 and others.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE.  Please take the [tour] to see how our Q&A site works. Each answer should stand on its own, as this is not a discussion forum.  Your answer looks like a comment on another answer.  It has the makings of a good answer.  Please edit/improve it to make it stand on its own in answer to the question, without referring to the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Today they refer to it as "from birth to earth" or from "womb to tomb".  Jesus meant that he there for us from the very beginning of our existence all the way to our dying day and home to heaven.

Comment: Welcome! We're glad you are here, but this answer would be much stronger if you showed, with sources, that it doesn't merely reflect your opinion.  I hope you'll take a minute to review [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576), and better understand how [your answer can be supported](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/692/21576).